# Urxvt draws lines slowly

Tags: command-line, terminal, arch-linux, urxvt

I'm using Arch Linux and Urxvt as terminal emulator. When I scroll up/down, text lines gets rendered so slow I can count by top to bottom (*heh, 1st line get rendered... ohh, 2nd one! ...*). It takes like a full second to get new content rendered in terminal. The worst is reading man pages, looking at Git's log etc.. I have no conf for Urxvt, so it can't me misconfed. The strangest thing is that on both other computers that are also running Arch Linux and Urxvt with almost the same conf everything works. Also, it can't be performance problems — hardware is quite new.

Any clue why's that? I even don't know where to start searching for problem!

Comment: My two bets would be: (1) something with font used by rxvt-unicode, (2) issues with compositing and hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I got shortcut for opening urxvt which called the terminal with addition arguments (“-lsp 2 -bc“). Removing arguments solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment it was quite the opposite! Adding `-lsp 1` made my `urxvt` fast.